# bash command output shows two identical lines

Tags: linux, debian

on my laptop , Debian 11 installed , to display lightdm.conf at first I used this command

```
~$ /usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config 
   [Seat:*]
-----------
Sources:
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf   ---> same as above
C  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/lightdm.conf
D  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

then I tried

```
~$ sudo lightdm --show-config 
   [Seat:*]
----------
Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
B  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/lightdm.conf
C  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

which gives normal output . I tested two other disks with debian 11 and a third one with Debian testing installed and none showed this doubled line *B /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf*. So , what can be wrong with my laptop ?

if it helps :

```
root@Xfce:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

~$ sudo printenv PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

~$ sudo which lightdm
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

```
~$ strace -e /open /usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
----------- /lib omitted
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf", O_RDONLY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf", O_RDONLY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/charset.alias", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/xfce4/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/lightdm.conf", O_RDONLY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf", O_RDONLY) = 6
```

all the machines with ( Debian 11 or testing ) including my laptop give :

```
~$ printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share
```

and XDG_CONFIG_DIRS are identical .
Thank you for helping , I will follow in this track .

- But if I remove one /usr/share from XDG_DATA_DIRS on my laptop then I have the right output with only one line B .

Comment: For one you didn't run `/usr/sbin/lightdm` with `sudo`. Also instead of `echo $PATH`, you should probably check `sudo printenv PATH`. (Not that any of these is necessarily relevant to your question, but let's be "scientific".)

Comment: You may also check `sudo which lightdm`, in case that's what you are interested to know.

Comment: Can you share the output of `strace -e /open /usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config` (you can omit the library files at the beginning, the ones that contain something with .../lib...). My guess here is that, when you are running it as a user, there is some user config being parsed (probably somewhere in `~/.config/`?) that includes the files in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` a second time.

Comment: I also think there's some user config involved.

Comment: "XDG_DATA_DIRS and XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"... RIGHT! Because (maybe it was not very clear in my reply), these are BOTH checked, so if you have "/usr/share" in both of those, it will be also parsed 2 times, as it happens for you.

Comment: Actually, reading again your edit, I see `/usr/share` already twice in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`. So if, as you say `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` is identical, I would expect the directories to be parsed 4 times instead of 2 (tested locally, and that's what happens indeed).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the strace output, that didn't show any user config being the cause of this double parsing, since `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` is being parsed twice before any other attempts at config files.

Checking through the [lightdm source code](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm) it looks like the directories to parse are chosen by calling `g_get_system_data_dirs()` and `g_get_system_config_dirs()`. These are methods from glib, which, according to the documentation, e.g. [here](https://libsoup.org/glib/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-user-data-dir), get the list of directories to parse from the environment variables `XDG_DATA_DIRS` and `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`.

I guess you have `/usr/share` two times in those variables for some reason (possibly some duplication in some .bashrc file?), so it is getting parsed twice (the `lightdm` part in `/usr/share/lightdm` is added from lightdm itself).

When you run it with sudo, your environment variables are not used, and I guess `XDG_DATA_DIRS` and `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` get some default values that include `/usr/share` just once, as expected.

**UPDATE**
For clarity, based on your latest edit, both `XDG_DATA_DIRS` and `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` are checked, so since you have `/usr/share` once in each of these, that's why you get the duplication.